# Replacement Battery for a 2005 Ford Focus

Tags: ford, battery, focus

I need to replace the battery on my 2005 Ford Focus. The battery indicated is a 590 CCA. I live in a very mild climate in Seattle. Rarely gets below 20 degrees here in the winter. Is there any reason I should go for a higher CCA or stick with the manufactutrer's suggested 590?

Comment: Was your original 590 CCA battery causing you cold start issues? If not, no reason to increase. If so, go for it. Your battery is part of your car, which is a tool you use to help you in your daily life; do what you need to do to make sure it meets *your* needs. If it ain't broke...

Answer (score 2):

There is no reson to exceed the OEM requirement, or spend the extra money to purchase battery capacity you don't need.  I think you need a BCI Group Size of "96R" ...

If you were running accessories with the vehicle off for extended periods, off-roaded the vehicle, or had a large lightbar, huge stereo amplifiers, or other add-on things, it might be a consideration.

I sincerely doubt you have any of these.  Stick to the original group size of battery.

Note that different aftermarket batery manufacturers may have a different CCA rating for the same group size.  You can safely ignore these slight differences.